# [next-auth][error][client_fetch_error] NextAuthJS CredentialsProvider "providers SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Tags: node.js, next.js, next-auth

As a beginner in Next.js I came across NextAuthJS. I wanted to use custom email and password authentication and thus I went with Credentials Provider and configured as below

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from `next-auth/providers/credentials`

import ConnectToDB from "../../../lib/db";
import auth from "../../../lib/auth";

export default NextAuth({
    session: {
        jwt: true,
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
    },
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            async authorize(credentials) {
                const client = await ConnectToDB();
                const db = client.db();

                const user = await db.collection("users").findOne({ email: credentials.email });

                if (!user) {
                    client.close();
                    throw new Error("User not found");
                }

                const isValid = await auth.verifyPassword(credentials.password, user.password);

                if (!isValid) {
                    client.close();
                    throw new Error("Invalid password");
                }

                client.close();
                return { _id: user._id };
            },
        }),
    ],
});
```

And used the `signIn` method from `next-auth/client` to signin as below

```
import { signIn } from "next-auth/client";

const submitHandler = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const email = emailRef.current.value;
        const password = passwordRef.current.value;
        const result = await signIn("credentials", { redirect: false, email, password });
}
```

I tried to debug this and found no solution to but and later I realised that some error is being logged in to browser console

[image]

This is the error I am receiving

> [next-auth][error][client_fetch_error]

Comment: Have you properly configured the `NEXTAUTH_URL` environment variable?

Comment: You are getting ```404``` error. This means that you are sending the request to an undefined route

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you already solved your problem since it's been a while you asked the question.
if not i'm intending my answer for also those who has the same issue.

Your code looks almost exactly the same in my one project but mine is working fine.
[image]
Well, you need to define `credemtials: {}` object in the `CredentialsProvider({ ... })` like the official doc example https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers/credentials.

The `client_fetch_error` error. I assume, you are getting this in production, i had this issue also. You need to add a environment variable:
[image]
and redeploy.

you should either `return null` or `return user` in the `authorize`, not `throw error`

Comment: The documentation says that you don't have to set this variable, when deploying to vercel, as it's automatically detected (https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options)

Comment: @Max i red so but if i don't define it, it gave me this error. It was fixed by add the env

Comment: @A: Can confirm this, solved the problem for me as well!

Comment: In case someone runs into this problem suddenly, happened to me as well. Vercel domain was getting detected just fine until a random commit. After that, was being thrown the above error and setting URL manually fixed it.

Comment: The same thing as Yo_Its_Az also just happened to me - it has been working fine, and suddenly has stopped working - and manually adding the NEXTAUTH_URL on our vercel deployment fixed the issue

Comment: Right answer. Happens only in production

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I needed to add NEXTAUTH_SECRET variable to Vercel, and the error was fixed. You can generate it with `openssl rand -base64 32`

more about that here: https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#secret